# im printing out my linkedList but the first element isnt printing why is that

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test

{

    static List<Integer> list  = new LinkedList<Integer>();

     public static void main(String[] args)

     {


        Scanner scanOne = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter integers to be added to the list with a space between every number : ");
        String name = scanOne.next();

        Scanner scanTwo = new Scanner(scanOne.nextLine());


        while (scanTwo.hasNextInt())
        {
            list.add(scanTwo.nextInt());

        }

        print();


     }


    public static void print()
    {

        ListIterator<Integer> listIT = list.listIterator();    // using the list Interface's method "listIterator()" to Iterate through the listIT

        while(listIT.hasNext()) 
        {
            int n = listIT.next();
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Please, format better your title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made a simple error. You've called next() and then nextLine(), so the printing starts at the second element.

```
    String name = scanOne.next();
    Scanner scanTwo = new Scanner(scanOne.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the first read element to the list:

```
String name = scanOne.next();
```

Read an int here and put it to the list as all the others.